# Теоретический вопрос про return

Tags: javascript

В конце функции мы пишем `return` и говорим, что функция "возвращает" например какое либо значение переменной. А вот куда функция его возвращает ? Для консоли есть функция `console.log()`, для вывода на экран есть `alert()`. Значение переменной мы можем запомнить если объявили ее вне функции.

И если не сложно можно пример, как использовать значение возвращенные с помощью `return` ?

Comment: Возвращает значение программе, которая эту функцию вызвала, если там есть присвоение, то значение становится присвоеным туда куда присвоили, `y=f(x)` после return из f, значение будет в y. Если `y=` отсутствует - значение теряется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция возвращает своё значение тому обращению, которое его вызвало:

```
function add(n) {
  return n + n
}

let ten = add(5) // ten получит return функции add(5), то есть значение 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот имеется условная функция createMassive() куда ты передаешь определенные аргументы и она создает тебе массив, и его ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ.
то есть например вот так -

```
var newMassive = createMassive("собака", "Кот", "рыба");
```

А функция например вот что делает

```
function createMassive(cat, dog, fish) {
  return [cat, dog, fish];
}
```

То есть получается это можно понять как

```
var newMassive = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
```

Это самый простой пример, но думаю понятный.

Comment: Зачем добавлять в выполняемый код, который в итоге ничего не делает?

Comment: может потому что форум скрывает код который не написан с помощью этого функционала? Мне вроде + говорили что за такое блочат.

Comment: Убрал лишнее обрамление. И в порядке уточнения: SO - это не форум; код не скрывает (если не указано специально); блочат не за такое )

Comment: значит мне наврали)

Comment: Скорее всего просто недопонимание, ничего страшного )